# bash: awk split string with a delimiter but not if it occurs in a bracketed string

Tags: bash, awk, split

I've the following script with input that is not parsing correctly as a result of the chosen string delimiter appearing in a string value.

I'm not exactly sure why the output is as it is, but basically the problem appears to be because of the evalue= in the following input:

```
avalue=one;bvalue=2.2.2.2;cvalue=3;dvalue=4.4.4;evalue=(HELLO:5;ABC:value=123.456);
```

containing the delimiter. of the

```
| awk ' { n=split($0,pcv,";") ;
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the delimiter regexp to not delimit if it occurs within brackets ( ) or even if the character before and after are 5;A

I know I can do this with modification of the input string with sed, but think it's best to do it in the awk.

```
pcvtmp='avalue=one;bvalue=2.2.2.2;cvalue=3;dvalue=4.4.4;evalue=(HELLO:5;ABC:value=123.456); fvalue=five;gvalue=six;hvalue=7;ivalue=eight.8;jvalue=(HELLO:5;ABC:value2=onetwothree);kvalue=9999999;'


       pcv=`echo $pcvtmp | awk ' { print $1 } ' \
                         | awk ' { n=split($0,pcv,";") ;
                                   for(i=1;i<n;i++){
                                   split(pcv[i],a1,"=");
                                        #printf (" debug: \"%s\" | \"%s\",\n", a1[1], a1[2]);
            if( a1[1]=="avalue")        {printf ("   a\"avalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
            if( a1[1]=="bvalue")        {printf ("   b\"bvalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
            if( a1[1]=="cvalue")        {printf ("   c\"cvalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
            if( a1[1]=="dvalue")        {printf ("   d\"dvalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
            if( a1[1]=="evalue")        {printf ("   e\"evalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
            if( a1[1]=="fvalue")        {printf ("   f\"fvalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
            if( a1[1]=="gvalue")        {printf ("   g\"gvalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
            if( a1[1]=="hvalue")        {printf ("   h\"hvalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
            if( a1[1]=="ivalue")        {printf ("   i\"ivalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
            if( a1[1]=="jvalue")        {printf ("   j\"jvalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
            if( a1[1]=="kvalue")        {printf ("   k\"kvalue\": \"%s\",\n"      , a1[2] ); continue } ;
                                   }
                                 } '`

                    echo "outof awk --"
                    echo "$pcv"
```

current output it:

```
# ./awk1.sh
outof awk --
   a"avalue": "one",
   b"bvalue": "2.2.2.2",
   c"cvalue": "3",
   d"dvalue": "4.4.4",
   e"evalue": "(HELLO:5",
```

expected output

```
# ./awk1.sh
outof awk --
   a"avalue": "one",
   b"bvalue": "2.2.2.2",
   c"cvalue": "3",
   d"dvalue": "4.4.4",
   e"evalue": "(HELLO:5;ABC:value=123.456)"    
   f"evalue": "five"
   g"gvalue": "six"
   h"hvalue": "7"
   i"ivalue": "eight.8"
   j"jvalue": "(HELLO:5;ABC:value2=onetwothree)"
   k"kvalue" "9999999"
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Provide a verifiable sample i/p and expected o/p

Comment: just added expected output in edit. thanks for looking!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this gnu awk command for splitting on `;` while ignoring `;` inside `(...)`:

```
pcvtmp='avalue=one;bvalue=2.2.2.2;cvalue=3;dvalue=4.4.4;evalue=(HELLO:5;ABC:value=123.456); fvalue=five;gvalue=six;hvalue=7;ivalue=eight.8;jvalue=(HELLO:5;ABC:value2=onetwothree);kvalue=9999999;'

awk -v FPAT='[[:alnum:]_]+=(\\([^)]*\\)|[^;]+)' '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      sub(/=/, "\": \"", $i)
      print substr($i, 1, 1) "\"" $i "\""
   }
}' <<< "$pcvtmp"

a"avalue": "one"
b"bvalue": "2.2.2.2"
c"cvalue": "3"
d"dvalue": "4.4.4"
e"evalue": "(HELLO:5;ABC:value=123.456)"
f"fvalue": "five"
g"gvalue": "six"
h"hvalue": "7"
i"ivalue": "eight.8"
j"jvalue": "(HELLO:5;ABC:value2=onetwothree)"
k"kvalue": "9999999"
```

Tricky part is using `FPAT` with this regex:

```
[[:alnum:]_]+=(\\([^)]*\\)|[^;]+)
```

which forms fields for each `key=value` pair. Here key is 1 or more word character followed by `=` and value is `(...)` or anything but `;`.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know the `FPAT` internal variable for `awk`

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ cat sp.awk

function key() {
    match(line, /^[^=]+/)
    tok  = substr(line, 1, RLENGTH) 
    line = substr(line, RLENGTH + 1)
}

function eat(s) {
    line = substr(line, length(s) + 1)
}

function val() {
    if (match(line, /^\(.*\)/) || # try with brackets
        match(line, /^[^;]+/)) {  # try without brackets
       tok  = substr(line, 1, RLENGTH)
       line = substr(line, RLENGTH + 1)
    } else {
       print "fail to read" | "cat 1>&2"; exit(1)
    }
}

{
    line = $0
    while (length(line)) { # `line' and `tok' are global
        key(); k = tok
        eat("=")
        val(); v = tok
        eat(";")
        print k, v
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f sp.awk file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

figured this out eventually with a search on key/pair and messing around at this site:

https://regex101.com/r/NwCI3b/1

This works as the regex;

```
((?:\([^\)]*\)|[^=;])*)=((?:\([^\)]*\)|[^=;])*)
```

or this:

```
([^=,]*)=((?:\([^\)]*\)|[^=;])*)
```

Where the test string is as above:

```
avalue=one;bvalue=2.2.2.2;cvalue=3;dvalue=4.4.4;evalue=(HELLO:5;ABC:value=123.456);fvalue=five;gvalue=six;hvalue=7;ivalue=eight.8;jvalue=(HELLO:5;ABC:value2=onetwothree);kvalue=9999999
```

Comment: That regexp will not work with any standard UNIX tool. Posting a regexp that some online tool thinks might be useful in some context is useless without the context.

Comment: yep you're right. I can't get it to parse as expected from within a bash script.

Comment: @TheHCD: Remember you posted this as awk problem originally :)